# Construct a vector with elements in-place

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a vector of smart pointers. So far I can construct them in a loop like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>());
```

I don't want to do this though. I want something like the following:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v(10, std::make_unique<int>());
```

This does not work. It seems like vector only has a constructor that will create copies or default-insert. So can I accomplish this? If the answer is no, what is the reasoning? In the future I would like to see a constructor that will allow the above.

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v(10);`
`std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::make_unique<int>);`

From <algorithm>.

Comment: @cie or generate n and an inserter?

Comment: @user467 By the way, you have a bug in the first snippet. It creates a vector with 20 elements.

Comment: *I don't want to do this though. I want something like the following* Why? I cannot see any significant advantage.

Answer (score 5):

You can use algorithm  generate:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v(10);
std::generate (v.begin(), v.end(), []() { return std::make_unique<int>(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T, class A, class F>
std::vector<T, A> generate_vec( size_t n, F&& f ){
  std::vector<T, A> retval;
  retval.reserve(n);
  std::generate_n( std::back_inserter(retval), n, std::forward<F>(f) );
  return retval;
}
// usually you don't want to bother to pass an allocator:
template<class T, class F>
std::vector<T> generate_vec( size_t n, F&& f ){
  return generate_vec<T, std::allocator<T>>( n, std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

now

```
auto v=generate_vec<std::unique_ptr<int>>(
  30,
  []{return std::make_unique<int>(); }
);
```

does what you want.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe640c60686b4765)

Comment: Making generate vec deduce its type is also possible, but somewhat dangerous.

Comment: default template argument value preceedeng to one without default template argument value

Comment: @Orient you are going to make me actually make my code compile, aren't you?  *sigh*, woe is me.... ok done.